# VBA: Range.Copy to Copy Part of Column

Tags: vba, excel

So I have two sheets. One is full of data with headers in row 1 (Sheet1) and the other has headers in row 9 (Sheet2). I need to copy the data from Sheet1 with a certain header and put it in Sheet2 with the corresponding header. For example, if the header in Sheet1 is "bob", I want to copy all of the data in the column headed with "bob" and place it in a hard-coded column in Sheet2.

My code currently filters through the headers in Sheet1 and when it selects the one I need to copy to the other sheet, it copies the *entire* column and pastes it into Sheet2 in column I. This column will always be the same, but I'd like the information to paste into I9 rather than at I1. I found some code online that helped with some modification.

However, I can't do this because copying the entire column creates issues when I try to paste, an error 1004. So I can only paste into I1, otherwise there is an overflow. How can I change my copy method so that only cells in the column with header "bob" that are filled are copied, and then pastes?

Code is below:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
Dim colName As String
Dim i As Integer

'activate temp worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set res = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With ws
    Set a = .Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="bob", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    'if found
    If Not a Is Nothing Then
        'copy column
        a.EntireColumn.Copy
        'insert column at I9
        Cells("I9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Else
        MsgBox "Parameter (bob) not found in (Sheet1)"
    End If

End With
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't copy the whole column, just copy the bit with data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range, a As Range`
Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
Dim colName As String
Dim i As Integer


'activate temp worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set res = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With ws
    Set a = .Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="bob", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    'if found
    If Not a Is Nothing Then
        'copy column
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, a.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(1, a.Column), .Cells(lRow, a.Column)).Copy
        'insert column at I9
        res.Range("I9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Else
        MsgBox "Parameter (bob) not found in (Sheet1)"
    End If

End With
```

Comment: I got a runtime error 5 on the line "res.Cells("I9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues" . I don't think it likes "Cells". Do you know how to fix that? This is farther than I've managed to get, thank you!

Comment: Use `Range`  instead of `Cells`